# What class to use for lookup value?

Tags: c#, winforms, list

I am building a C# windows form that displays a listbox with some items to select from to a user.  That selection will determine the criteria for a query.  The query will return 2 fields, an ID and a description.  I want to display the description in a second listbox on the form but use the ID for subsequent processing if that description is selected in the list box.

Here's some more details about what I am trying to do:

```
ListBox1
Accessories
Men's
Women's
Children
```

When the user selects 'Accesories' a query runs and returns:

```
1234   Belts
2345   Scarves
4566   Handbags
```

ListBox2 displays the descriptions

```
Belts
Scarves
Handbags
```

But when the user double clicks on Belts I want to add 1234 to a field in class instance.  What kind of list should I put the results of the query into so that I can use it to add Items to my list box and still be able to know the ID?

Thanks!
Leslie

Answer (score 2):

Both WinForms and WPF are quite flexible. Just add the Accessory objects to the Items property. Or set DataSource to an existing list.

The default display is through `ToString()` but you can set DisplayMember to the name of a specific property.

You can get at the entire object through SelectedItem. And/or set ValueMember and read SelectedValue.

Comment: except Accesories isn't an object...it is just the criteria for the query that I added to the list box items.  I am more interested in what you say by "set DataSource to an existing list."  how would I do that?

Comment: I assume the data ends up somewhere... In a DataTable or something. Either a `List<>` or a DataTable can be assigned directly to `DataSource`. Using a BindingSource (like Delphi's TDataSource) is optional.

Comment: Ok I will try to figure that out instead...I guess I am struggling with how to assign the same thing 2 values and use one in one place and the other in another without creating a class like was suggested below.

Comment: Bind to the datatable (set the combobox datasource to your dataset), set DisplayMember to the fieldname for the desciption, and ValueMember to the fieldname for the key.

Answer (score 2):

In the .NET list boxes, the item list is not just a list of strings, but *objects*.  The component will use the string value of the object for display, but you can reference the ID when you look at the selected value.

Define a class thusly

```
class Choices
{
   public string Name;
   public int ID;

   public override string ToString()
   {
      return name;
   }
}
```

Populate the list with instance of this class, and you should be good to go.